# TypeError: Cannot destructure property 'id' of 'question' as it is undefined

Tags: typescript, caching, next.js, prisma, zod

I am using the t3 stack for this project and its basically a web app where users can answer questions and share their thoughts. I've been working on a favorite functionality, and it's now bothering me. The problem is that when I try to favorite a post, I get this error:

```
TypeError: Cannot destructure property 'id' of 'question' as it is undefined.

input: RouterInputs["questions"]["getQuestions"];
  11 | }) {
> 12 | const { id } = question;
     |        ^
  13 | 
  14 | return (
  15 |     <>
```

The question can never be null though, can't figure out why id isn't there. It was working before I separated my post/card component into two separate ones. If I check for null and assign an empty object, the problem occurs in the next component instead. Again, not sure why those objects are null when I believe they shouldnt be.
Code below.

This is where I encounter the error. FeedQuestion and QuestionCard used to be the same component, but because I needed QuestionCard elsewhere, I thought it could be its own component and I'd wrap it in a different component if necessary.

```
function FeedQuestion({ question, client, loggedIn, input }: {
    question: RouterOutputs["questions"]["getQuestions"]["items"][0];
    client: QueryClient;
    loggedIn: boolean;
    input: RouterInputs["questions"]["getQuestions"];
}) {
    const { id } = question;
    return (<>
            <Link href={`/debate/${id}`}>
                <QuestionCard question={question} client={client} loggedIn={loggedIn} input={input} />
                <div className="block max-w-sm p-4 bg-white rounded-lg shadow-inner" >
                    {"Most popular argument"}
                </div>
            </Link>
        </>)}
export default FeedQuestion;
```

This is the feed/timeline, where I display a list of questions

```
function QuestionsFeed() {

    const { data: session } = useSession();

    const scrollPosition = useScrollPosition();

    const searchParams = useSearchParams();
    const hotFilter = searchParams.get('hot');
    const typeFilter = searchParams.get('type');

    let where = {}, orderBy = {};

    if (hotFilter) {
        const now = new Date();
        where = {
            createdAt: {
                gte: new Date(now.getFullYear(), now.getMonth() - 1, now.getDay()),
            },
        };
        orderBy = {
            arguments: {
                _count: Prisma.SortOrder.desc,
            }
        };
    }
    else if (typeFilter) {
        where = {
            type: typeFilter as Type,
        };
        orderBy = {
            id: Prisma.SortOrder.desc,
        };
    }
    else {
        orderBy = {
            id: Prisma.SortOrder.desc,
        };
    }

    const input = {
        where,
        orderBy,
    }

    const { data, hasNextPage, fetchNextPage, isFetching } = api.questions.getQuestions.useInfiniteQuery(
        input,
        {
            getNextPageParam: (lastPage) => lastPage.nextCursor,
        },
    );

    const client = useQueryClient();

    const questions = data?.pages.flatMap((page) => page.items) ?? [];

    useEffect(() => {
        if (scrollPosition >= 90 && hasNextPage && !isFetching) {
            fetchNextPage();
        }
    }, [scrollPosition, hasNextPage, isFetching, fetchNextPage]);

return (
        <div>
            <ul className="flex flex-col gap-10 pt-24 pb-4">
                {
                    isFetching ? pulseLoadingCardAnimation() :
                        questions?.map((q, index) => {
                            return (
                                <li key={index}>
                                    <FeedQuestion question={q} client={client} loggedIn={session ? true : false} input={input} />
                                </li>
                            );
                        })
                }
            </ul>
            {!hasNextPage && <p className="text-neutral-400 pb-4">These are all of our questions for now!</p>}
        </div>
    )
```

QuestionCard component

```
function QuestionCard({ question, client, loggedIn, input }: {
    question: RouterOutputs["questions"]["getQuestions"]["items"][0],
    client: QueryClient;
    loggedIn: boolean;
    input: RouterInputs["questions"]["getQuestions"];
}) {
    const { title, id, favoritedBy } = question;

    const favoriteQuestion = api.questions.favorite.useMutation({
        onSuccess: (data, variables) =>
            updateCache({ client, data, variables, action: "favorite", input }),
    }).mutateAsync;

    const unfavoriteQuestion = api.questions.unfavorite.useMutation(
        {
            onSuccess: (data, variables) =>
                updateCache({ client, data, variables, action: "unfavorite", input }),
        }
    ).mutateAsync;

    const hasFavorited = favoritedBy.length > 0;
    return (
        <>
            <div className="block max-w-lg p-6 bg-white rounded-lg shadow" >
                <div className="flex justify-end">
                    <AiFillHeart
                        color={loggedIn ? hasFavorited ? "purple" : "gray" : "lightgray"}
                        size="1.5rem"
                        onClick={(e) => {
                            e.preventDefault();
                            e.stopPropagation();
                            if (!loggedIn) {
                                return;
                            }

                            if (hasFavorited) {
                                unfavoriteQuestion({
                                    questionId: id,
                                });
                                return;
                            }

                            favoriteQuestion({
                                questionId: id,
                            });
                        }}
                    />
                </div>
                <div className="">
                    <h5 className="mb-6 text-4xl font-bold tracking-tight text-black">{title}</h5>
                </div>
            </div>
        </>
    );
}
```

Thank you for your help.

Comment: Is your repository open-source? If yes, could you share it so that I can try to debug it locally?

Comment: Yes I can open-source it. https://github.com/SoftDevCHD/Versy. Thanks for your help.

Comment: Thanks for sharing, I'll clone it and debug

Comment: The ```id``` in ```const { id } = question;``` in your object is not null. You would not have a problem destructuring if it was. The problem is that the ```id``` field does not exist in your question object - that is to say, ```id``` is ```undefined```. As per the ```QuestionCard``` snippet, you are sending the question object with the field ```questionId```. I think you have to destructure ```const { questionId } = question;```. I may be wrong, but could you check.